# Convert Vec<T> to Vec<U> when From<T> for U is available

Tags: rust, type-conversion, traits

I have implemented `From<T> for U`, and expected that I could call `Vec<U>::extend` with a `Vec<T>`. Instead I get `expected T, got U`. What's the most idiomatic way to fix this?

```rust
struct U;
struct T;

impl From<T> for U {
    fn from(_other: T) -> Self {
        U
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<U> = Vec::new();
    let other: Vec<T> = Vec::new();

    v.extend(other.into_iter());
}
```

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::vec::IntoIter<T> as std::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == U`
  --> src/main.rs:14:7
   |
14 |     v.extend(other.into_iter());
   |       ^^^^^^ expected struct `T`, found struct `U`
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
              found type `U`
```

Comment: Type conversions are _mostly_ explicit in Rust. I think `From::from` is only called implicitly when using the `?` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [`Extend::extend`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html) takes an iterator:

```
fn extend<T: IntoIterator<Item = A>>(&mut self, iter: T);
```

You can actually use map adaptor:

```rust
let mut v: Vec<U> = /**/;
let other: Vec<T> = /**/;

v.extend(other.into_iter().map(<U as From<T>>::from));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=16646b30106fff8ea60dfb31b6cf358b).
Or you could elide the specific `From` implementation and let the compiler "do the ugly thing for you" as @Stargateur mentioned in the comments:

```
v.extend(other.into_iter().map(From::from));
```